# Create URI with machine name and .domain name

Tags: c#, wcf

maybe I will not correct explain a problem, maybe somebody help me explain this problem.
So, I have next task: create instance of URI with name of PC, like this:

```
baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", Dns.GetHostName() ,port ));
```

But if PC in domain I need to use extended PC name like this:
    **pcname.company.com**

For this case I used next code

```
baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", Dns.GetHostName() + "." + Environment.UserDomainName ,port ));
```

And here I found problem :(

Name of domain can be **company.com** but can be **company_system**. I use this syntax for different cases for example :
If I wont to login on my PC I can write **myname@company.com** and I can write **company_system\myname**.

And question:

How to find domain name in format like this **company.com** because by default `Environment.UserDomainName` returns domain name like **company_system**?

Thank you!

Regards,

Jitm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).HostName

GetHostEntry returns name of PC with  domain and domain in correct format like this:

**pcname.company.com**